# How to display a large e-mail file containing html code and attachments

Tags: html-email

I have a large file (about 200 MB) which I should analyse, without file extension, with basically unknown content, but seemingly containing an email, a lot of html-code and several base64 encoded attachments (application/octet-stream):

```
Subject: XXX Hello 
Date: Mon, 16 June 2020 10:11:00 +0100
From: CN=Name Name2/OU=XXX/O=XXXX
Content-type: multipart/mixed;
        Boundary="0__=C6BB0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Sensitivity:
Keywords:
X-MIMETrack: CD-MIME by java.exe on _/_(Release 11.0.1FP3|(date)) at (date)
 (time),CD-MIME complete at (date time),Itemize by java.exe on _/_(Release 11.0.1FP3|(date)
 (time)


--0__=C6BB02D7DFxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-type: multipart/related;
        Boundary="1__=C6BB0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


--1__=C6BB0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-2022-JP
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body>
<table width=3D"100%" border=3D"1">
....
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</body></html>
--1__=C6BB0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-type: image/gif; name="xxxx.gif"
Content-ID: <0__=C6BB0yyy@local>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

R0lGODXXXXXXXXAAAAP(base64 code here)A7


--1__=C6BB0yyy

...
```

Renaming it with suffix .html and unsing google-chrome I can see a table with some content, but it seems I have to extract the attachments manually. Is there a more elegant way of displaying it in the original way?